# Build for Pdf not working properly in Springer template

Tags: templates

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.7.12) 23 DEC 2019 09:04
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**ewaste.tex
(./ewaste.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
Package: fix-cm 2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
Now handling font encoding TS1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding TS1
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu
File: ts1enc.dfu 2018/04/05 v1.2c UTF-8 support for inputenc
 defining Unicode char U+00A2 (decimal 162)
 defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
 defining Unicode char U+00A4 (decimal 164)
 defining Unicode char U+00A5 (decimal 165)
 defining Unicode char U+00A6 (decimal 166)
 defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
 defining Unicode char U+00A8 (decimal 168)
 defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
 defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
 defining Unicode char U+00AC (decimal 172)
 defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
 defining Unicode char U+00AF (decimal 175)
 defining Unicode char U+00B0 (decimal 176)
 defining Unicode char U+00B1 (decimal 177)
 defining Unicode char U+00B2 (decimal 178)
 defining Unicode char U+00B3 (decimal 179)
 defining Unicode char U+00B4 (decimal 180)
 defining Unicode char U+00B5 (decimal 181)
 defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
 defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
 defining Unicode char U+00B9 (decimal 185)
 defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
 defining Unicode char U+00BC (decimal 188)
 defining Unicode char U+00BD (decimal 189)
 defining Unicode char U+00BE (decimal 190)
 defining Unicode char U+00D7 (decimal 215)
 defining Unicode char U+00F7 (decimal 247)
 defining Unicode char U+0192 (decimal 402)
 defining Unicode char U+02C7 (decimal 711)
 defining Unicode char U+02D8 (decimal 728)
 defining Unicode char U+02DD (decimal 733)
 defining Unicode char U+0E3F (decimal 3647)
 defining Unicode char U+2016 (decimal 8214)
 defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
 defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
 defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
 defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
 defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
Click here to access/download;Manuscript;ewaste.tex
Click here to view linked References
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65 
 defining Unicode char U+203B (decimal 8251)
 defining Unicode char U+203D (decimal 8253)
 defining Unicode char U+2044 (decimal 8260)
 defining Unicode char U+204E (decimal 8270)
 defining Unicode char U+2052 (decimal 8274)
 defining Unicode char U+20A1 (decimal 8353)
 defining Unicode char U+20A4 (decimal 8356)
 defining Unicode char U+20A6 (decimal 8358)
 defining Unicode char U+20A9 (decimal 8361)
 defining Unicode char U+20AB (decimal 8363)
 defining Unicode char U+20AC (decimal 8364)
 defining Unicode char U+20B1 (decimal 8369)
 defining Unicode char U+2103 (decimal 8451)
 defining Unicode char U+2116 (decimal 8470)
 defining Unicode char U+2117 (decimal 8471)
 defining Unicode char U+211E (decimal 8478)
 defining Unicode char U+2120 (decimal 8480)
 defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
 defining Unicode char U+2126 (decimal 8486)
 defining Unicode char U+2127 (decimal 8487)
 defining Unicode char U+212E (decimal 8494)
 defining Unicode char U+2190 (decimal 8592)
 defining Unicode char U+2191 (decimal 8593)
 defining Unicode char U+2192 (decimal 8594)
 defining Unicode char U+2193 (decimal 8595)
 defining Unicode char U+2329 (decimal 9001)
 defining Unicode char U+232A (decimal 9002)
 defining Unicode char U+2422 (decimal 9250)
 defining Unicode char U+25E6 (decimal 9702)
 defining Unicode char U+25EF (decimal 9711)
 defining Unicode char U+266A (decimal 9834)
 defining Unicode char U+FEFF (decimal 65279)
))) (./svjour3.cls
Document Class: svjour3 2007/05/08 v3.2
LaTeX document class for Springer journals
Class Springer-SVJour3 Info: extra/valid Springer sub-package (-> *.clo)
(Springer-SVJour3) not found in option list of \documentclass
(Springer-SVJour3) - autoactivating "global" style.
(./svglov3.clo
File: svglov3.clo 2009/12/18 v3.2 style option for standardised journals
SVJour Class option: svglov3.clo for standardised journals
)
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 147.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 148.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 149.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 150.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 151.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 152.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 153.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 154.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 155.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 156.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 157.
\logodepth=\dimen102
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65 
\headerboxheight=\dimen103
\betweenumberspace=\dimen104
\aftertext=\dimen105
\headlineindent=\dimen106
\c@inst=\count80
\c@auth=\count81
\instindent=\dimen107
\authrun=\box26
\authorrunning=\toks14
\titrun=\box27
\titlerunning=\toks15
\combirun=\box28
\c@lastpage=\count82
\rubricwidth=\dimen108
\c@section=\count83
\c@subsection=\count84
\c@subsubsection=\count85
\c@paragraph=\count86
\c@subparagraph=\count87
\spthmsep=\dimen109
\c@theorem=\count88
\c@case=\count89
\c@conjecture=\count90
\c@corollary=\count91
\c@definition=\count92
\c@example=\count93
\c@exercise=\count94
\c@lemma=\count95
\c@note=\count96
\c@problem=\count97
\c@property=\count98
\c@proposition=\count99
\c@question=\count100
\c@solution=\count101
\c@remark=\count102
\c@figure=\count103
\c@table=\count104
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\figcapgap=\dimen110
\tabcapgap=\dimen111
\figgap=\dimen112
\bibindent=\dimen113
\@tempcntc=\count105
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65 
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen114
\Gin@req@width=\dimen115
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathptmx.sty
Package: mathptmx 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Times w/ Math, improved (SPQR,
WaS)
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version
`normal'
(Font) OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/ztmcm/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/ztmcm/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font) OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/ztmcm/m/it on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font) OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/ztmcm/m/it on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font) OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/ztmcm/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font) OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/ztmcm/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line
31.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version
`normal'
(Font) OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/ztmcm/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version
`bold'
(Font) OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/ztmcm/m/n on input line 31.
\symbold=\mathgroup4
\symitalic=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version
`normal'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/ptm/bx/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/ptm/bx/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version
`normal'
(Font) OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/ptm/m/it on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/ptm/m/it on input line 35.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \hbar on input line 50.
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/04/06 v1.3b Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks17
\inpenc@posthook=\toks18
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Posting the whole log file isn't very useful.  If there are error or warning messages, post those; if there aren't any, post the summary block at the bottom of the log.  That might provide enough specific information for someone to give better suggestions.

Comment: Basically, I have developed a latex document using the springer template in Texmaker 5.0.3, and the compilation is working fine. However, when I have submitted to the springer journal, the last stage "build for pdf approval" is showing an error and unable to develop a pdf. The error pdf contains the code that I have posted above.

Comment: @Rohit Which error do you get? I can only see parts of a log file, but no error message

Comment: The pdf builder of springer developed the pdf, I have included the starting pages above. Thus, the error is that the pdf is showing the code instead of paper that I have developed. Please suggest

Comment: Can anyone help regarding this problem

Comment: My document in texmaker is working fine. but unable to get the pdf in springer pdf builder.

Comment: same problem with references, did you find the solution?

Comment: @Rohit Did this get resolved?